# Unknown CMake command "add_service_files"

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

These are the code I include in my CMakeLists.txt

```
add_service_files(
  FILES
  AddTwoInts.srv
)
```

However, when I try to use `catkin_make` to build, the error says `Unknown CMake command "add_service_files"` and the error lies in the code above. However, I can't find anything wrong with these three lines of code.

Comment: Please provide additional details as to what your system setup looks like. e.g version of ROS you're using. Also, it might be useful to include the rest of the CMake file to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Sure, I use ROS::noetic and I have found the problem. I forgot to include `message_generation` in the find_package function in the cmakelists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the `message_generation` in the `find_package()`.
The complete section of code should be like below:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
```